# How do I get values of custom fields of jira service desk api in order to create the request?

Tags: java, api, rest, jira

How do I get values of custom fields from JIRA service desk api to create the ticket in getter and setter?
The field 'customfield_10600' is not valid for this request type 'Technical support'
For Eg: customfield_10600 is a fieldID that stores the email in JIRA dialog

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issue-fields/#api-rest-api-3-field-get).

> Get fields:
>
> /rest/api/3/field

and [this documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issue-custom-field-options/#api-rest-api-3-field-fieldid-context-contextid-option-get)

> Get custom field options:
>
> /rest/api/3/field/{fieldId}/context/{contextId}/option

Answer (score 0):

you can use also /rest/api/2/issue/{issueId}/editmeta